# Finding the differences between two 8 bit binary states

Tags: c++, math, binary

I'm not sure what is the technical term for what I'm trying to achieve, but what I need is the difference between two binary numbers.

Basically, I'm building a test fixture at work and I'm planning to store states in a PISO shift register, when I read from the SR, I want to compare it to another 8 bit number that is pre-determined, meaning if what I read from the SR is the same as the pre-determined binary number, I have correct state at that particular instance in time.

However, if the states are mismatched, then I want to know what is the "difference". So say:

10011000 -> pre-determined
10000100 -> reading from SR

then, the difference would be

00011100

not

00001100, which is the subtraction between the two,

is there a C++ function that does what I want?

Thank you

Comment: I think you want the `^` operator (also known as bitwise XOR)

Comment: Does this operator performs the operation on the bits individually? Sorry I don't have my computer with me

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what you need, so I posted this as an answer. Yes, each bit is xor-ed (the same as difference) individually (hence the name *bitwise* xor)

Comment: @BrendonCheung It seems you have asked quite a few questions but rarely accept any of the answers you've gotten. Perhaps you should go through your questions and accept the acceptible answers and ask for clarification if you don't understand the answers?

Answer (score 4):

`operator^` does exactly this.

For example:

```
const unsigned char state         = 0b10011000;
const unsigned char expected      = 0b10000100;
static_assert((state ^ expected) == 0b00011100);
```